# Backend in folder and frontend in another folder

Tags: asp.net-core, frontend, backend

simple question how to separate backend and frontend files in asp.net core
i want backend and frontend folders to keep things organized

my project uses asp.net core with blazor
the structure right now is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on your current scenario and project structure you could follow the below structure to make a cleaner project architecture.

**Blazor Project Structure:**

[image]

**Note:**

You have to take a solution under that solution you should take one `client` project and one `server` project and it will help to distinguish your `front-end` and `backend` code. If you want to share common stuff between them you could add `an additional class library` as well. [`You could refer to this example for more details`](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/BFF/tree/main/samples/Blazor6)